# How do I solve complex example using matrix?

Tags: matrices

> An airline provides air connections between cities $S_1, S_2, \dotsc
>  S_n$. Partially roundtrips are offered, other connections are
>   available but only in one direction. There may be no connections
>   between some cities.

I need to find out on which or how many ways you
can get to town $S_j$ with change from the city $S_i$. This is
achieved with the aid of so-called adjacency matrix $A$, using the
matrix product or the $k$-th power of matrices.

$A_{ij} = 1$ when $S_i$ directly can fly to $S_j$

$A_{ij} = 0$ when $S_i$ directly can not fly to $S_j$

In how many ways you can get from $S_i$ by $S_j$, if you want to
 change more than m times?

Comment: Is this for a general graph / adjacency matrix?

Comment: I don't know....

Comment: Oh, yes, my mistak.e Edited.

Answer (score 1):

$V_i$ is a column vector with $0's$ everywhere but the $i^{th}$ row, where it has a 1.

$AV_i$ then gives you the cities that you can reach directly from i.  That is, if there is a 1 in the $j^{th}$ row, you can fly from i to j.

The $j^{th}$ row of $A^2V_i$ will give you number of ways to get from i to j making one stop.

Comment: How do i know that Vi has 0's everywehre and i^th 1

Comment: I defined it that way.